# Having issues with troubleshooting Windows 7 wireless management

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I assembled a new desktop PC a few weeks back and finally made the jump from XP to 7. Since then, I've had nothing but problems with the Windows 7 wireless networking.

If there's a signal or connection problem I feel nearly helpless. XP gave me many more information and configuration options at my fingertips than I feel 7 does. So much so, that I'm on the look-out for a 3rd party wireless network manager app.

I'm open to the idea that after using XP for 9 years versus 2 weeks for 7 I may be overlooking some things, but I'd consider myself a poweruser and the distinct "don't worry, we'll fix it for you" impression I get from Win 7 is extremely irritating when the options available are so nebulous.

So, is it really just me, or is Windows 7's approach to managing wireless networks truly less usable and helpful? And if so, what can I do about it?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about the things that seem to be missing?  Apart, as you say from the rather superficial connection troubleshooter, all the same tools (ipconfig, netstat etc) are still available with Win7, and all the same advanced configuration of the individual adapters is just as possible as before.  I've moved to Win7 and so far it seems better in every way.

Comment: Your original post was likely to be closed for being too subjective, so I reworded it for you. When posting in the future, please consider the language you use. People are more likely to help you out if your question is phrased politely and in technical, rather than emotional, terms. I agree with @ChrisA that it would be helpful to know more information. What, specifically, can't you do in Windows 7 that you used to do in Windows XP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good internet connection manager is Lenovo Internet Connection (AKA Lenovo Access Connections). With this tool you can create profiles, and have them in an order of preferred networks. The profiles you create can be exported and used on other computers.

Also, I never noticed an issue with the way Windows 7 allows you to manage wireless networks. The only reason I use Lenovo Access connection is due to the fact that it allows you to prefer wired over wireless.

Good Luck -